# Show that the difference of indices of a $p$-subgroup in a group and its normalizer is a multiple of $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of finite group $G$, show that $p$ divides $[N (H): H] - [G: H]$, where $N (H) = \{g \in G | gH = Hg\}$.

I was able to prove that if $p$ divides $[G: H]$ then $p$ divides $[N (H): H]$, but I could not do the case where $p$ does not divide $[G: H]$, I tried to find some $N (H) H$ in some set, but I do not know what a good set for it ... I know that $N (H) / H$ is a group with the classical operation, since $H$ is normal in $N (H)$

Comment: H is any arbitrary subgroup?

Comment: I had forgotten to say that H was a p-subgroup

Answer (score 2):

I shall start from where you ended. If $H$ is a $ p$- subgroup such that $p$ does not divide $[G:H]$ then we have $H$ is a Sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$. By by Sylow's theorem #Sylow $p$ subgroups $=[G:N(H)] \equiv 1$ mod $p$. Now multiply both sides by $N(H):H$